# Does It Makes Sense to Have the Index of a Sum in the Argument of a Function? Two Examples Given with Integral and Sum.

Tags: integration, summation, radicals, index-notation, error-propagation

**Question 1**:

I have recently tried out answering a couple of questions with the method of using the same variable in the argument of a function and a sum for example:

$$\int_0^N (\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt x)^n dx= \lim_{N\to ∞}\sum_{k=0}^N f\biggl(a+k\frac{b-a}{N}\biggl )\frac{b-a}{N}= \lim_{N\to ∞}\sum_{k=0}^N f\biggl(0+k\frac{N-0}{N}\biggl )\frac{N-0}{N}=  \lim_{N\to ∞}\sum_{k=0}^N f(k)*1=  \lim_{N\to ∞}\sum_{k=0}^N  (\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k)^n= \sum_{k=0}^ ∞(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k)^n$$

Therefore, with a restriction:
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\bigg(\int_0^N (\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt x)^n dx= \sum_{k=0}^ N(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k)^n\bigg),1\ge n\in \Bbb R$$
Here is [proof](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lhbapjlcza) of the answer.

This works and even shows that the integral or sum operator does not matter up to a point. **Why does this work with the same operators and sum index bound in the integral bound?**

**Question 2**:

This is the main reason I made this question. Imagine with an easier example that:
$$S=\sum_{n\ge 1} 2^{-n} $$
This simple geometric series looks like the reimann zeta function, but with the wrong order of exponentiation where x is a function to be determined:
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} 2^{-n}=ζ(x)=\sum_{n\ge 1}n^{-x} $$

To solve for x, equate the like expressions:
$$2^{-n}= n^{-x}⇒x=-\log_n(2^{-n})=n\log_n(2)$$
Therefore n is in the argument of the Riemann Zeta function as $x(n)$:
$$S=ζ(n\log_n(2))= \sum_{n\ge 1}2^{-n}, \mathrm {restrictions}$$

However, this obviously does not work unless x(n) is plugged into the Riemann Zeta definition. What would this mean, if anything, to have an argument as an already defined index of a function and why does this fail? Please give me feedback and correct me!

Sorry if this question is trivial. I am genuinely curious about this peculiar property and you may be as well.

Comment: This is not valid. When taking a Riemann sum, the variable $N$ in the summand must not depend on any variable in the function.  The sum and integral are not equal here even in the limit (when it is convergent) - you are making an approximation.

Comment: @JairTaylor Yes, looking at the graphs of these functions by letting n vary gives similar graphs  with the integral being slightly greater than the sum for n>0. This reminds me if the integral test for sums. They appear to be the least close in the range of n between 2 to 4 inclusive.